# Why is Port 80 blocked from the outside of my network?

Tags: firewall, internet-connection, port-forwarding

I have one domain (website) and one home computer. On my home computer I installed software for mobile recharge. This system has a static IP.

So I send a recharge request (HTTP request) to my home computer using my website. The concept is: Every request is processed and sends a response to my website. But whenever I send the request, the home system port 80 is blocked.

My home system has no firewall enabled and no anti-virus software installed. So why does my port 80 appear to be blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your router to forward the request to your web server computer.
(This is called port forwarding; you need to forward port 80 to the IP of the server)

Note that many ISPs block incoming requests to port 80, so you may need to use a different port (eg, 81).

Comment: ok thanks how to set port forwarding in my router?

Comment: That depends on the router.  Go to the router's IP and explore, or Google the model name.

Comment: ok thanks just now i google the concept thank you.